# No logro Eliminar registro usando livewire y laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, livewire

Estoy probando laravel 9 con livewire pero al momento de intentar eliminar algunos registros no me toma el click del boton,  me regiero mas bien a que no elimina el registro, este es todo el codigo de mi controlador:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;
use App\Models\Airplane;
use Livewire\WithPagination;

class Airplanes extends Component
{
    use WithPagination;
    
    public $view = 'create';
    public $dataAirplane;
    
    // Disponibilizacion de variables para editar y crear, para las vistas del front
    public $name, $color, $model, $brand, $patent, $quantity, $date, $country;
    
    public function render()
    {
        $dataAirplane = Airplane::orderBy('id', 'asc')->paginate(10);
        return view('livewire.airplane', compact ('dataAirplane'));
    }


    // FUNCION CREAR
    public function save()
    {
        $this->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
            'model' => 'required',
            'brand' => 'required',
            'patent' => 'required',
            'quantity' => 'required',
            'date' => 'required',
            'country' => 'required'
        ]);
        Airplane::create([
            'name' => $this->name,
            'color' => $this->color,
            'model' => $this->model,
            'brand' => $this->brand,
            'patent' => $this->patent,
            'quantity' => $this->quantity,
            'date' => $this->date,
            'country' => $this->country,
        ]);
        // RESETEA LOS INPUT
        $this->reset();
    }

    // FUNCION EDITAR GENERA VISTA DE LOS DATOS QUE SE MODIFICARAN EN LOS INPUT
    public function edit($id)
    {
        $airplane = Airplane::find($id);
        $this->name = $airplane->name;
        $this->color = $airplane->color;
        $this->model = $airplane->model;
        $this->brand = $airplane->brand;
        $this->patent = $airplane->patent;
        $this->quantity = $airplane->quantity;
        $this->date = $airplane->date;
        $this->country = $airplane->country;
        $this->view = 'edit';
    }

    // FUNCION ACTUALIZAR
    public function update()
    {
        // VALIDANDO DATA
        $this->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
            'model' => 'required',
            'brand' => 'required',
            'patent' => 'required',
            'quantity' => 'required',
            'date' => 'required',
            'country' => 'required'
        ]);
        // REGISTRO QUE SE ACTUALIZARÁ A TRAVÉS DE ID
        $airplane = Airplane::find($this->id);
        //  SE ESTÁ ACTUALIZANDO LA DATA
        $airplane->update([
            'name' => $this->name,
            'color' => $this->color,
            'model' => $this->model,
            'brand' => $this->brand,
            'patent' => $this->patent,
            'quantity' => $this->quantity,
            'date' => $this->date,
            'country' => $this->country,
        ]);
    }

    public function destroy(Airplane $airplane)
    {
        
            $airplane->delete();
        
    }
}
```

Aqui en el controlador probe dejando la variable dataAirplane como publica pero aun asi no me funciona, hago click al boton de eliminar y no toma nada, es como si nunca llamar a la funcion destroy...

Luego tengo mi vista blade de esta forma, dentro del foreach leo la data y tengo el llamado a la funcion destroy para el boton eliminar:

```
<x-app-layout>

    <x-slot name="header">
        <h2 class="font-semibold text-xl text-gray-800 leading-tight">
            {{ __('Airplane') }}
        </h2>
    </x-slot>
    <div class="flex justify-end sm:px-5 lg:px-5 py-3 mr-32">
        <button wire:click='save' class="btn-primary bg-indigo-500 hover:bg-indigo-600 font-bold text-white rounded-lg px-7 py-2">
            Crear</button>
    </div>

    <div class="flex flex-col max-w-7xl mx-auto sm:px-2 lg:px-2">
        <div class="overflow-x-auto sm:-mx-36 lg:-mx-48">
            <div class="py-4 inline-block min-w-full sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
                <div class="overflow-hidden">
                    <table class="min-w-full text-center table-auto">
                        <thead class="border-b bg-gray-800">
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="col" class="text-sm font-medium text-white px-6 py-4">
                                    ID
                                </th>
                                <th scope="col" class="text-sm font-medium text-white px-6 py-4">
                                    Nombre
                                </th>
                                <th scope="col" class="text-sm font-medium text-white px-6 py-4">
                                    Color
                                </th>
                                <th scope="col" class="text-sm font-medium text-white px-6 py-4">
                                    Modelo
                                </th>
                                <th scope="col" class="text-sm font-medium text-white px-6 py-4">
                                    Marca
                                </th>
                                <th scope="col" class="text-sm font-medium text-white px-6 py-4">
                                    Patente
                                </th>
                                <th scope="col" class="text-sm font-medium text-white px-6 py-4">
                                    Cantidad
                                </th>
                                <th scope="col" class="text-sm font-medium text-white px-6 py-4">
                                    País
                                </th>
                                <th scope="col" class="text-sm font-medium text-white px-6 py-4">
                                    Fecha
                                </th>                                
                                <th scope="col" class="text-sm font-medium text-white px-6 py-4">Editar</th>
                                <th scope="col" class="text-sm font-medium text-white px-6 py-4">Borrar</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            @foreach ($dataAirplane as $aviones)
                            <tr class="bg-white border-b">
                                <td class="text-sm text-gray-900 font-light px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">
                                    {{$aviones->id}}
                                </td>
                                <td class="text-sm text-gray-900 font-light px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">
                                    {{$aviones->name}}
                                </td>
                                <td class="text-sm text-gray-900 font-light px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">
                                    {{$aviones->color}}
                                </td>
                                <td class="text-sm text-gray-900 font-light px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">
                                    {{$aviones->model}}
                                </td>
                                <td class="text-sm text-gray-900 font-light px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">
                                    {{$aviones->brand}}
                                </td>
                                <td class="text-sm text-gray-900 font-light px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">
                                    {{$aviones->patent}}
                                </td>
                                <td class="text-sm text-gray-900 font-light px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">
                                    {{$aviones->quantity}}
                                </td>
                                <td class="text-sm text-gray-900 font-light px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">
                                    {{$aviones->country}}
                                </td>
                                <td class="text-sm text-gray-900 font-light px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">
                                    {{$aviones->date}}
                                </td>                             
                                <td>
                                    <button class="text-sm bg-green-600 hover:bg-green-700 text-white font-bold px-6 py-3 rounded-lg">Editar</button>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <button type="button" wire:click.prevent="destroy({{$aviones->id}})" class="text-sm bg-red-600 px-5 hover:bg-red-700 text-white font-bold  py-3 rounded-lg">
                                        Borrar
                                    </button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            @endforeach
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</x-app-layout>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

tu ruta debe estar definida por el nombre de tu modelo 'model'.'destroy', seguido del 'id' del registro a eliminar.
revisa con el comando

> php artisan route:list y veras la ruta para el metodo destroy

`<button type="button" wire:click.prevent="{{ route('aviones.destroy', $aviones->id) }}" class="text-sm bg-red-600 px-5 hover:bg-red-700 text-white font-bold py-3 rounded-lg"> Borrar </button>`

tu método destroy debe de recibir solo el $id que quieres eliminar

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    
    $airplane = Airplane::find($id);
    $airplane->delete();
    
}
```